# String Exist Check and Echo to File

Tags: batch-file

For each folder in this directory:

```
"F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles"
```

Here are example folders in the above directory (the numbers are GPS coordinates):

```
zOrtho4XP_+65-023
zOrtho4XP_+65-024
zOrtho4XP_+65-025
zOrtho4XP_+66-015
zOrtho4XP_+66-016
```

Those `zOrtho4XP_*` folders contain satellite imagery which will be overlayed on the default scenery of the X-Plane 11 Flight Simulator.

In order for the satellite images to appear in the simulator, their folder **names** need to be added to the `scenery_packs.ini` file, which resides in 
`"E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini"`

Here is an example of the `scenery_packs.ini` file: *Note how it contains the folder **names** of the folders containing the satellite imagery*

```
SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/zOrtho4XP_+65-023/
SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/zOrtho4XP_+65-024/
SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/zOrtho4XP_+65-025/
SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/zOrtho4XP_+66-015/
SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/zOrtho4XP_+66-016/
```

These `zOrtho4XP_*` folders are downloaded in batches and some batches contain dozens of these `zOrtho4XP_*` folders, and each of those folder names have to be added to the `scenery_packs.ini` file. That's what I'm trying to avoid manually doing, because I'm going to be doing a lot of this in the coming weeks and I prefer to not have to manually add those folders line by line; it would be hundreds, if not over 1,000.

I've managed to scribble this up, but it's as far as my knowledge goes with batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles"
set "destination=E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini"

    for %%a in ("%target%") do (
        findstr %%~nxA 
        if exist IGNORE 
        )else(
        echo %%~nxA >> %destination% )

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Type `if /?` and learn the correct `if`/`else` syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles"
set "destination=E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini"

(
    for /d %%A in ("%target%\*") do @(
        >nul findstr /c:"SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/%%~nxA/" "%destination%" ^
        || echo SCENERY_PACK Custom Scenery/%%~nxA/
    )
) >> "%destination%"
```

This will get each subfolder name in the root of `%target%`.
`Findstr` will search in the `%destination%` ini file for the folder name pattern.
If failure, then the folder name pattern is echoed to `%destination%` file.

The `^` is a line continuation character as a line is long.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Michael. It worked perfectly and I got to learn how it works as I examined it. Thanks again! You've saved me SO much time already